# COBOL ERASE no funciona

Tags: cobol

Estoy viendo tutoriales de COBOL, usan la sentencia "ERASE" para limpiar la pantalla y no me funciona. El compilador indica "syntax error, unexpected ERASE"

El codigo es:

`DISPLAY "1.- CALC, 2.- CERRAR" ERASE.`

Estoy usando opencobol desde ubuntu (veo que dice 1.1.0).
Alguien sabe como borrar la pantalla o que funcione la sentencia ERASE?
Podrá ser que mi cobol esté desactualizado?

Answer (score 0):

Espero que te sirva todavía

OpenCobol, tiene varios errores al compilar porque no es un MVS "Mainframe", si es un código que no tenga que mostrar una pantalla para ingresar datos y dar un resultado, funciona bien, pero si no, entonces te arroja ese error por no estar en un MVS

Te recomiendo usar un MVS y un emulador de terminal 3270, para no tener esos problemas al compilar el código y hacer tus pruebas

La linea de codigo que escribiste esta correcta

Aquí te dejo otro ejemplo

```
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01  NOMBRE PIC X(30).
01  OP PIC X.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
INICIO.
       DISPLAY 'PROGRAMA DE SALUDO' LINE 1 ERASE.
       PERFORM PIDENOMBRE.
       DISPLAY 'HOLA ' LINE 10.
       DISPLAY NOMBRE LINE 10 COL 6.
       ACCEPT OP LINE 20.
       STOP RUN.
PIDENOMBRE.
       DISPLAY 'INTRODUZCA EL NOMBRE ..' LINE 20.
       ACCEPT NOMBRE LINE 20 COL 30 PROMPT.
       DISPLAY SPACES LINE 20 SIZE 70.
```